# What is the difference between CPU Revision and Revision fields for arm processors?

Tags: android, linux, cpu, procfs

Making a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` on Android returns this kind of output:

```
    Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 1 (v7l)
    processor   : 0
    BogoMIPS    : 38.00

    processor   : 1
    BogoMIPS    : 38.00

    processor   : 2
    BogoMIPS    : 38.00

    processor   : 3
    BogoMIPS    : 38.00

    Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32
    CPU implementer : 0x51
    CPU architecture: 7
    CPU variant : 0x2
    CPU part    : 0x06f
    CPU revision    : 1

    Hardware    : Qualcomm MSM8974PRO-AC
    Revision    : 0000
    Serial      : 0000000000000000
```

I do not find the meaning difference between those two fields:

- CPU revision
- Revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CPU revision:** It Indicates patch release or "minor revision". In your case it is 1. So this value is specific to your CPU. You can see that CPU revision is matching to `Processor   : ARMv7 Processor` **rev 1** `(v7l)`

You can refer to attached image for the details of other filled as well.

[image: CPUID bit assignment]

**Revision:** It is related to your hardware (board) configuration. In your case your are using the Qualcomm hardware so revision number depends upon on it. It is independent of the CPU revision number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :).